# Can't insert any values in Judy

Tags: php, arrays, php-extension

I'm getting strange behavior with Judy Array. The documentation just says you can use it like an usual PHP array. But whatever I do it seems to me that it won't store any information.

For example if I do this:

```
$this->_history = new Judy(Judy::STRING_TO_MIXED);
$this->_history['test'] = 'testString';
echo $this->_history['test']; // output nothing; no warnings no text nothing
var_dump($this->_history); // class Judy#126 (0) { }
$this->_history->getType() // correctly (int) 5
$this->_history->getTypeFoo() // warning no method
```

Am I doing something wrong? Did I forget something? I tested it both an an Ubuntu and Debian System, both the same.

Also funny is, that when I run the bench-script which is provided in the `pecl` package and extracted under `/usr/share/php/doc/Judy/examples/judy-bench-string_to_int.php` the Judy Array works fine.

Here's how I installed it:

```
sudo aptitude install libjudydebian1 libjudy-dev
sudo pecl install judy
```

It said installation was succesful and I added `extension=judy.so` to `php.ini`.
What should I do to get Judy working?

Comment: Try `{$this->_history}['test']` for grouping.

Comment: Are you running this inside an object method? `$this` won't exist unless you're actually INSIDE an instantiated object.

Comment: Yes I run this inside a Class method.

Comment: Well if I do `{$this->_history}['test']` I will get unexpected "}" error.

Comment: Are you sure your error reporting, as set in your PHP config, will show warnings and notices on-screen?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Also if I do `$this->_history->getType()` he correctly returns `5`. And if I do `$this->_history->getTypeFoo()` he gives warning that this method aint exists.

Answer (score 1):

Well it works now. But actually I don't know why. I shouldn't care.
I copied the working code from the `bench-*.php` file from the `/docs` into my own file and it worked. Here's the code:

```
echo "\n-- Judy STRING_TO_INT \n";
echo "Mem usage: ". memory_get_usage() . "\n";
echo "Mem real: ". memory_get_usage(true) . "\n";

$s=microtime(true);
$judy = new Judy(Judy::STRING_TO_MIXED);
for ($i=0; $i<500; $i++)
    $judy["$i"] = 'test';
var_dump($judy);
unset($judy["102"]);
echo $judy["192"];
var_dump($judy["102"]);
echo "Size: ".$judy->size()."\n";
$e=microtime(true);
echo "Elapsed time: ".($e - $s)." sec.\n";
echo "Mem usage: ". memory_get_usage() . "\n";
echo "Mem real: ". memory_get_usage(true) . "\n";
echo "\n";

unset($judy);
```